# Implementing loss function for training GAN

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, gan

I am trying to understand the implementation of the following loss function in training Discriminator part.

```
Loss function  maximize log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
```

Code

```
############################
    # (1) Update D network: maximize log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
    ###########################
    # train with real
    model_D.zero_grad()
    real_cpu = data[0].to(device)
    batch_size = real_cpu.size(0)
    label = torch.full((batch_size,), real_label, device=device)
    output = model_D(real_cpu)
    errD_real = loss_function(output, label)
    errD_real.backward()
    D_x = output.mean().item()

    # train with fake
    noise = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_vector_size, 1, 1, device=device)
    fake = model_G(noise)
    label.fill_(fake_label)
    output = model_D(fake.detach())
    errD_fake = loss_function(output, label)
    errD_fake.backward()
    D_G_z1 = output.mean().item()
    errD = errD_real + errD_fake
    train_loss_D += errD.item()
    optimizerD.step()
```

These two lines
`output = model_D(real_cpu) errD_real = loss_function(output, label)` implement `log(D(x))`.

But I can't understand for the following lines implement this `log(1 - D(G(z))`. I just see `log D(G(z))` and where is 1 and substraction?

```
noise = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_vector_size, 1, 1, device=device)
fake = model_G(noise)
label.fill_(fake_label)
output = model_D(fake.detach())
errD_fake = loss_function(output, label)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loss_function` in the source code is a `BCELoss`, which can be represented as

$$L = -(1-b)log(1-a)-blog(a)$$

where `b` represents the labels, which takes the values 0 or 1, and `a` represents the `output` of `model_D`.

In the training with real data`x`, labels `b` all take 1. Therefore the loss can be represented as

$$L_{real}=-log(a)=-log(D(x))$$

which maximizes `log(D(x))`.

In the training with fake data`G(z)`, labels `b` all take 0. Therefore the loss can be represented as

$$L_{fake}=-log(1-a)=-log(1-D(G(z)))$$

which maximizes `log(1-D(G(z)))`.

The total loss can be represented as

$$L_{total}=L_{real}+L_{fake}$$

which maximizes `log(D(x))+log(1-D(G(z)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the loss function in the 'train with real' block same with the loss function in the 'train with fake' block? If they were the same function, the implement should be wrong due to the lack of 1 and substraction. If not, maybe you can show the internal code of these two loss functions and we can judge then.

Comment: The whole code is in `https://github.com/batuhanguler/Deep-Convolutional-GAN/tree/master`. DCGAN.ipynb has implementation.